# How to create decorator that add argument to function

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

How to make a decorator that adds an argument to a function? Is it possible? Could you set a default value for the new argument? Here is an example of work:

```py
>>> @add_argument('bob', default=None)
... def simple(a, b):
...   return a + b
... 
>>> print(inspect.signature(simple))
<Signature (a, b, bob=None)>
```

The challenge is not to change the behavior of the function when it is inspected through inspect, but to directly add one more argument to the function.

Comment: Which version of Python are you actually asking about?

Comment: As you can see from the tags, I'm interested in both Python 2 and Python 3

Comment: How would the decorated function access that additional parameter?

Comment: I don't know, that's my question, besides the ability to set default is optional

Comment: It's not a case of adding arguments to the decorated function - the decorator can return a _new_ function, with whatever signature it wants.

Comment: hmm, can you give an example?

Comment: @QwertYou _all_ decorators are some form of a function which returns a function! this gives an opportunity to add any arguments you like https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-decorator

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Decorator to Find the Time of Execution of a Function in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67547781/decorator-to-find-the-time-of-execution-of-a-function-in-python)

Comment: no, I understand this, and in this regard, my question is somewhat incorrect and it should sound more correct, how to make a decorator that returns a new function with the same behavior and a new argument, which would be called the same as the decorator argument and is it possible. No one answered this question